# Execute Join in If statement

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I want to join a bunch of columns from different tables in the same database in mysql. The problem I have, is that not all values are written in the same table.
The concrete example: In one table there is the *sid* column. Depending on the value in this column the next values I need in this join are located in different tables. If the *sid* value equals 1 I have to join with table 2 to get the values I want, if the *sid* value is anything but 1 I have to join with table 3.
I researched a bit into if - else in mysql but all the information I can find is about changing values and how they are displayed under certain conditions.
I want the workflow to change under certain conditions.

No matter which join gets executed, the resulting table has the same amount of columns. I do not actually display any data from table 2 and table 3. The *descr* column exists in table 4. All the other displayed columns exist in table 1. So there should not be any problems wit the display.

The code looks as follows (inspired by python):

```
SELECT type, s_type, id, descr
FROM table1
IF sid = 1 THEN
    LEFT JOIN table2
    ON table1.sid = table2.sid
    LEFT JOIN table4
    ON table2.sid = table4.id_name
ELSE
    LEFT JOIN table3
    ON table1.sid = table3.svid
    LEFT JOIN table4
    ON table3.svid = table4.id_name
END IF;
```

What is the correct way to get this control flow done in mysql?

Comment: Please qualify the column names so it is clear where they come from.

Comment: Do separate queries that join with the appropriate tables, and combine them with `UNION`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IF` cannot be used by this in SQL.  If I understand the logic, you *could* do something like this:

```
SELECT type, s_type, id, table4.descr
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN
     table2
     ON table1.sid = table2.sid AND table1.sid = 1 LEFT JOIN
     table3
     ON table1.sid = table3.svid AND table1.side <> 1 LEFT JOIN
     table4
     ON table4.id_name = COALESCE(table3.svid, table2.sid)
```

If your tables are large, the `COALESCE()` might be a performance killer.